# Can Applescript be used to tell whether or not a directory (path) exists?

Tags: applescript

I've got some Applescript code that switches to a specified directory by KEYSTROKEing the path into the "Go To" dialog.

Regretfully, this dialog does **NOT** raise an error if the requested directory does not exist?! It just goes as far as it can along the path and then **DUMPS THE NONEXISTENT PATH FRAGMENT into the default text field of whatever window is under it**!

Example: given "~/Music/nonexistent" it would switch to the Music folder in the user's home folder then 'type' "nonexistent" into the underlaying window's default text field if it has one.

Consequently, I need to know how to find out if a given path already exists or not from Applescript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In AppleScript you can simply check if a path exists by coercing the path to an `alias` specifier. If the path does not exist an error is thrown

Further you have to expand the tilde programmatically. The handler returns a boolean value.

```
on checkPathExists(thePath)
    if thePath starts with "~" then set thePath to POSIX path of (path to home folder) & text 3 thru -1 of (get thePath)
    try
        POSIX file thePath as alias
        return true
    on error
        return false
    end try
end checkPathExists

set pathisValid to checkPathExists("~/Music/nonexistent")
```

Alternatively use `System Events`, but sending an Apple Event is a bit more expensive:

```
set thePath to "~/Music/nonexistent"
tell application "System Events" to set pathisValid to exists disk item thePath
```

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this?

```
set theFolder to "path:to:the:Folder:" --your folder/path


if FolderExists(theFolder)=true then -- HERE YOU DON'T have to put exists again, it's already check in the handler FolderExists(theFolder)

      display dialog "Exists " & theFolder & " !"

else

      display dialog "Missing " & theFolder & " !"

end if

--handler for checking if exists theFolder/thePath

    on FolderExists(theFolder) -- (String) as Boolean
        tell application "System Events"
            if exists folder theFolder then
                return true
            else
                return false
            end if
        end tell
    end FolderExists
```