# How do I create a directory path in Applescript?

Tags: applescript

The supposed duplicate question explains how to **DELETE A FILE** but I need to **CREATE ONE (OR MORE) NONEXISTENT DIRECTORIES** a completely different task!

As a followup to my previous (solved) question [Can Applescript be used to tell whether or not a directory (path) exists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42058669/can-applescript-be-used-to-tell-whether-or-not-a-directory-path-exists)

I now need to know how to create any directories in the path that do not already exist?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AppleScript set directory path in Finder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124232/applescript-set-directory-path-in-finder)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Applescript to make new folder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493335/applescript-to-make-new-folder)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to use the shell, `mkdir -p` creates the folder only if it does not exist.

```
do shell script "mkdir -p  ~/Desktop/TestFolder"
```

However there is a caveat: If there is a space character in the path you need to replace every space with two backslashes because the  usual `quoted of` does not expand the tilde.

```
do shell script "mkdir -p  ~/Desktop/Test\\ Folder"
```

Alternatively

```
set thePath to "~/Desktop/Test Folder ABC"
if thePath starts with "~" then
    set quotedPath to text 1 thru 2 of thePath & quoted form of (text 3 thru -1 of thePath)
else
    set quotedPath to quoted form of thePath
end if

do shell script "mkdir -p  " & quotedPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `POSIX file` before the path to get a file object:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to POSIX file "/Users/username/Documents/new.mp3"
    if exists f then delete f
end tell
```

`system attribute "HOME"` is replaced with `/Users/username`:

```
set f to POSIX file ((system attribute "HOME") & "/Documents/new.mp3")
tell application "Finder" to if exists f then delete f
```

Or use the pre-OS X path format:

```
tell application "Finder"
    set f to "Macintosh HD:Users:username:Documents:new.mp3"
    -- set f to (path to documents folder as text) & "new.mp3"
    if exists f then delete f
end tell
```

Bron: [AppleScript set directory path in Finder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16124232/applescript-set-directory-path-in-finder)

Answer (score 0):

If your question is still:

"CREATE ONE (OR MORE) NONEXISTENT DIRECTORIES a completely different task?"

In order to manage my folders, I use those lines in the relevant case:

Create all the folders from "a" to "e". If folder "a" already exists then from "b" to "e".
etc...

```
set mkdirFolder to "mkdir -p " & desktopPath & "a/b/c/d/e/"

do shell script mkdirFolder
```

Create a folder "a" if not exists and folders "b to e" at his top-level

```
set mkdirFolder to "mkdir -p " & desktopPath & "a/{b,c,d,e}/"
        do shell script mkdirFolder
```

Create folder with a part of the name

```
-- (Note the single quotes round the space to mark it as part of the name.)
    set mkdirFolder to "mkdir -p " & desktopPath & "a/Chapter' '{1,2,3,4}/"

do shell script mkdirFolder

result--> Folders "Chapter 1", "Chapter 2", "Chapter 3", and "Chapter 4" are created in folder "a"
```

You can find more informations here ([Learn more about creating folder with "mkdir"](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=16156))

Comment: Here you can see desktopPath as variable but you can put any other path with slashes. Correct me if I'm wrong.